# Removing default items from Hunchentoot server

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

Hunchentoot comes with some default files that it serves without having any new handlers added. They are stored in `/path/to/hunchentoot/www/`. I can't figure out how to stop them from being served. I've tried looking at `*dispatch-table*` and `*easy-handler-alist*` but nothing is there, and I can't find a way to remove them anyway. Is there a way to at least make it 404 when one of those pages is requested without removing all the files from that directory (which would get restored on update)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These files are found through the value of the acceptor's `document-root` slot. You can override this when creating the acceptor:

```
(make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor :port 8080 :document-root "/my/docs/")
```

Just point that into an empty directory to serve nothing by default.

If necessary, the error page templates that are located in `www/errors/` can be read from elsewhere by setting the `error-template-directory` slot in a similar way.